# Android 2.2 and EPublib

Tags: android, epub

I get this error when I try to compile epub for android.

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lnl/siegmann/epublib/browsersupport/NavigationEvent;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:372)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:346)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:59)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:294)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:313)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:233)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:185)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:90)
```

Comment: This question lacks real substance. Please improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to allow internet on the manifest file, add the following line :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`